# matching dot in a range preg_match

Tags: php, regex

I have been trying to match a literal dot `.` using `preg_match()`, but the regex engine complains at the position of the `\.`.

What is wrong here and how can I fix it?

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9_-\.]{3,16}$/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a malformed character class. Use

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9_.-]{3,16}$/
```

You are getting [- Text range out of order error](https://regex101.com/r/yF4nD3/1). You do not have to escape a hyphen at the final position in the character range. If you use it *inside* the character class, you must escape it.

Inside the character class, almost all characters are treated as literals, *except for* closing bracket `]`, the backslash `\`, the caret `^`, and the hyphen `-`. (see [Metacharacters Inside Character Classes at Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#special)).

The caret at the non-initial position will also be treated as a literal. If `]` is at the initial position, it does not have to be escaped in PHP (but must be escaped in JavaScript!).

From [PCRE reference](http://pcre.org/pcre.txt):

> 16. Perl, when in warning mode, gives warnings  for  character  classes
>          such  as  `[A-\d]` or `[a-[:digit:]]`. It then treats the hyphens as literals. **PCRE has no warning features, so it gives an error in these  cases because they are almost certainly user mistakes.**

Comment: So, to be on the safe side, always use a hyphen at the end or at the start of a character class. Less typing, less worries :)

Comment: do these rules apply to javascript too??

Comment: Forgot about the dot: it does not have to be escaped at all in a character class, it will be always counted as a literal `.`. Yes, **the same rules are applied in JavaScript**.

Comment: :) Just updated, I copied the regex from your answer and first fixed the critical issue with the hyphen. Cool question BTW.

Comment: do these rules apply to javascript too?

Comment: You can check your regular expressions for PHP online at various sites like [regex101.com](http://regex101.com), or [phpliveregex.com](http://www.phpliveregex.com/) and quickly see if there are any issues with them.

Comment: and please include the `\.` explaination in the answer above.. as this was confusing for me whether dot should be escaped or not.

Comment: I have just added some more on escaping the characters inside a character class. I'd encourage you to make some tests on regex101.com. It is really a quick and handy tool for checking such nuances.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is presence of unescaped hyphen in the middle of character class. Fix it by:

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9_.-]{3,16}$/
```

Comment: hypen too has to be escaped??

Comment: If hyphen is in the middle of a character class then yes it needs to be escaped but if it is on the sides then it doesn't need to be escaped and yes dot also doesn't need to be escaped as you can see from my regex.